# algo.getNodeById Unknown function - Graph Algorithms book

Tags: neo4j

This is related to the examples found in this book:
https://neo4j.com/graph-algorithms-book/

I appreciate that a similar question was asked a while back but the answer was to use a later version of NEO4J.

I'm currently trying to follow the examples in the Graph Algorithms book and have what I assume is the latest version of the software (downloaded a week ago). Desktop Version: 1.2.1, Database version: 3.3.2

So, why am I getting this error?

The code is from page 90 of the book:

```
WITH "https://github.com/neo4j-graph-analytics/book/raw/master/data/" AS base
WITH base + "social-relationships.csv" AS uri
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM uri AS row
MATCH (source:User {id: row.src})
MATCH (destination:User {id: row.dst})
MERGE (source)-[:FOLLOWS]->(destination)

WITH "https://github.com/neo4j-graph-analytics/book/raw/master/data/" AS base
WITH base + "social-nodes.csv" AS uri
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM uri AS row
MERGE (:User {id: row.id})

CALL algo.closeness.stream("User", "FOLLOWS", {improved: true})
YIELD nodeId, centrality
RETURN algo.getNodeById(nodeId).id AS user, centrality
ORDER BY centrality DESC
```

Error is:

```
Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Unknown function 'algo.getNodeById' (line 3, column 8 (offset: 104))
 "RETURN algo.getNodeById(nodeId).id AS user, centrality" ^
```

As per the earlier answer to the question, the following code works but gives a different answer to what is shown in the book (David has a centrality of 8 versus 1 in the book answer):

```
CALL algo.closeness.stream("User", "FOLLOWS")
YIELD nodeId, centrality
MATCH (node) where id(node) = nodeId
RETURN node.id as user, centrality
ORDER BY centrality DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed you have the latest desktop version of Neo4j, but your database version is really old, we are now at the **3.5.11**.

And because the graph algo lib is linked to the database version, you also have an old one.

If you upgrade your database then everything should be fine.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks! I was surprised because I had only just downloaded the software from the official site. I found the upgrade databse option and this seems to work!